# delete same value listbox and arraylist

Tags: c#, arraylist, listbox

```
foreach (Student student in liststu)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(student.ToString());
}
foreach (Staff staff in liststa)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(staff.ToString());
}
```

I have two arraylist `liststa` `liststu` that is used to fill my listbox. I'm trying to delete from listbox and arrylist at the same time , I'm trying to do with `Remove()` but I don't know how to get the correct value from listbox for delete in the arraylist.

```
for (int i = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndices[i]);
    liststa.Remove(listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()); 
}
```

how I get the correct value from listbox for use arraylist's  `Remove()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `.Remove` is trying to find the specific string by value, not by index.

For example, you're trying to remove the string "2" from an ArrayList of objects, *not* index 2

It sounds like you wish to remove by index, so simply use `.RemoveAt` on the arraylist as well

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndices[i]);
liststa.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndices[i]);
```

This obviously requires that listtsa and listBox1 are kept in sync

Comment: its giving error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." i try this before listbox position and arraylist position is different i think because i m loading another list to list box too ,

Comment: deleting by string better solution to me

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the selected item value from the List not the selectedIndex only
Also you have to delete from the ArrayList before the List

try this

```
int selectedIndex;
for (int i = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
selectedIndex=listBox1.SelectedIndices[i];
liststa.Remove(listBox1.Items[selectedIndex].ToString()); 
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: still arraylist non deleted

Answer (score 0):

can you try to remove by index but remove from the ArrayList before the list as the following

```
int selectedIndex;
for (int i = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
selectedIndex=listBox1.SelectedIndices[i];
liststa.RemoveAt(selectedIndex); 
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: this code working but i have two arraylist loading same listbox,,

Comment: Why don't you merge the 2 arraylists into one?